# How to find the sum $\sum_{m = 0}^{M - 1}e^{i m \mathbf{a}_1 \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k}}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, physics

My question is fundamentally a matter of mathematics, but it is based in physics. My textbook, *Solid-State Physics, Fluidics, and Analytical Techniques in Micro- and Nanotechnology*, by Madou, says the following in a section on **X-Ray Intensity and Structure Factor $F(hkl)$**:

> Assume now a crystal with base vectors $\mathbf{a}_1$, $\mathbf{a}_2$, and $\mathbf{a}_3$ and a total number of atoms along each axis of $M$, $N$, and $P$, respectively, and also accept that there is only a single atom at each lattice point (i.e., $f_j = 1$), then the amplitude of the total wave will be proportional to:
>
> $$\begin{align} \Psi(x, t) \propto F(h, k, l) &= \sum_{\text{all atoms}} e^{i(r_j \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k})} \\ &= \sum_{m = 0}^{M - 1} \sum_{n = 0}^{N - 1} \sum_{p = 0}^{P - 1} e^{i[(m \mathbf{a}_1 + n \mathbf{a}_2 + p \mathbf{a}_3) \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k}]} \end{align}$$
>
> after rearrangement we obtain:
>
> $$\Psi(x, t) \propto F(h, k, l) = \sum_{m = 0}^{M - 1} e^{im \mathbf{a}_1 \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k}} \sum_{n = 0}^{N - 1} e^{in \mathbf{a}_2 \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k}} \sum_{p = 0}^{P - 1} e^{ip \mathbf{a}_3 \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k}} \tag{2.38}$$
>
> The intensity of the scattered wave is the square of the wave amplitude, and taking the value of one of the sums in Equation 2.38 for a crystal of dimension $M\mathbf{a}_1$ in the direction $\mathbf{a}_1$, we obtain:
>
> $$\sum_{m = 0}^{M - 1}e^{i m \mathbf{a}_1 \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k}} = \dfrac{1 - e^{iM(\mathbf{a}_1 \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k})}}{1 - e^{i(\mathbf{a}_1 \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k})}}$$

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain how we deduce that $\sum_{m = 0}^{M - 1}e^{i m \mathbf{a}_1 \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k}} = \dfrac{1 - e^{iM(\mathbf{a}_1 \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k})}}{1 - e^{i(\mathbf{a}_1 \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k})}}$.

Comment: geometric series $1+z+z^2+..z^{M-1}=\frac{1-z^M}{1-z}$ where $z=e^{i(\mathbf{a}_1 \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k})}$

Comment: I know nothing about complex analysis, so my guess could be wrong - but isn't this just the sum of a finite geometric series? See equation (6) of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html, and notice that (6) has $n$ as the upper index (whereas you have $M - 1$).

Comment: @Conrad It seems that you're both correct. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula Thank you for the clarification! Feel free to post an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Just FYI, if you multiplied through by $1-e^{i(\mathbf a_1\cdot\Delta\mathbf k)}$, the sum on the left will "telescope": every term but two will cancel out with another term identical except for being of the opposite sign. The two surviving terms are those in the numerator on the right-hand side. This is how Conrad's geometric series fomula is proved.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Does that mean that it's *also* a telescoping series?

Comment: "Also" a telescoping series? This is the very archetype of a telescoping series. The terminology was invented exactly to describe what happens when you multiply a geometric series by $1$ minus the first-order term.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Oh, ok. Thanks for the clarification.